# Can't get Twitter Typeahead to work in Bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js

This might be a noob issue, but I cannot figure out why this code is not working.  FYI this is just a sample list of counties pulled from a state with just a few.  I pull the list from php based on earlier inputs, but that is not the issue, the list is fine, its autocomplete not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/s4wx9/

```
<div>Local County:
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level required typeahead" id="county" name='county' placeholder="Local County" />
    <div>

<script>
    $("#county").typeahead({
        local: ["Apache", "Cochise", "Coconino", "Gila", "Graham", "Greenlee", "La Paz", "Maricopa", "Mohave", "Navajo", "Pima", "Pinal", "Santa Cruz", "Yavapai", "Yuma"]
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `local` by `source` in your javascript

```
$("#county").typeahead({
        source: ["Apache", "Cochise", "Coconino", "Gila", "Graham", "Greenlee", "La Paz", "Maricopa", "Mohave", "Navajo", "Pima", "Pinal", "Santa Cruz", "Yavapai", "Yuma"]
    });
```

Local is used with the standalone Typeahead library.

EDIT: Here's an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s4wx9/1/

Comment: Thanks, that got the fiddle working, but for some reason its not on my website.  I have no console errors to reference

Comment: It was a different typo.  WOrks now.  THanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems

1. You are using a very old version of bootstrap(2.1.1) which is not compatible with jquery 1.9 version (There are many [deprecated features removed](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/) in this version including the [$.browser](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed) extension which is used by bootstrap) - if you cannot upgrade to a new version of bootstrap for the time being you can include the [migration plugin](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin) to fix this problem
2. need to set the source option instead of local

try

```
$("#county").typeahead({
    source: ["Apache", "Cochise", "Coconino", "Gila", "Graham", "Greenlee", "La Paz", "Maricopa", "Mohave", "Navajo", "Pima", "Pinal", "Santa Cruz", "Yavapai", "Yuma"]
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/S2p54/)

Comment: oops, my website uses 2.3.2, this was an adaptation of another fiddle, i never noticed the age

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't i get this error in console: Uncaught Error: one of local, prefetch, or remote is required jquery.js:6974
b.extend.error jquery.js:6974
d typeahead.min.js:7
(anonymous function) typeahead.min.js:7
b.extend.map jquery.js:7187
b.initialize typeahead.min.js:7
jQuery.fn.typeahead typeahead.min.js:7
(anonymous function) srv_info.php:982
c jquery.js:7341
p.fireWith jquery.js:7403
b.extend.ready jquery.js:6875
H jquery.js:6601

Comment: @srt8driver I think you are using the stanalone typeahead

Comment: yes <script src="js/include/typeahead.min.js"></script> should I do something different?  (THis is my first bootstrap project)

Comment: @srt8driver still you need to use the migrate plugin I think http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cUu4B/1/

Comment: Since Bootstrap 2.3.2 already includes it I have pulled the standalone reference from my site.  I got it working with my css/js in fiddle but it wont work on my site.  and no console errors to point me at the issue

Comment: Had a typo on my page - once fixed all it needed was the source change.

Answer (score 0):

It works to me.
Run this Code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>

<div>Cnty:
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level required typeahead" id="county" name='county' placeholder="Local County" />
    <div>


<script>
$("#county").typeahead({
   source: ["Apache", "Cochise", "Coconino", "Gila", "Graham", "Greenlee", "La Paz", "Maricopa", "Mohave", "Navajo", "Pima", "Pinal", "Santa Cruz", "Yavapai", "Yuma"]
    });
</script>
```

Include:These above

```
jquery-2.1.1.min.js
bootstrap.min.css
bootstrap.min.js
```

You are done. Thanks.